# Sort dropdown by class and headings

Tags: python, django

Here's a tricky one...
I have my models as showed below.
I'm showing Class C in a dropdown as it shows in the model (c,b,a).

I would like order it by b and show it in a better way, with a heading for each b.

But I would like to show it as:

***B(A)***

c

c

c

c

Then again:

***B(A)***

c

c

```
 Class A(CodeList)
        Class Meta:

Class B(Models.Model)
    Name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A);
    def __unicode__ (self) :
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.a.name);
    def a_name(self) :
        return self.a.name;

Class C(Models.Model)
    Name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B);
    def __unicode__ (self) :
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.b.name, self.a.name);
    def b_name(self) :
        return self.b.name;
    def a_name(self) :
        return self.a.name;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The ordering should be the easier part. Just set the 'ordering' option in the C's Meta options. Here's the corresponding part of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

Grouping is a bit trickier. I don't think there's a way around subclassing the Select-widget and overriding its render-method.